# HTTP GET: Same GET-Parameter multiple Times, is this allowed by RFCs?

Tags: http

are all "Standard Compliant (HTTP RFC?)" Web-Servers forced to "somehow" provide some methods to get all Parameters with the same name as some kind of list/array? Or will will using the same parameter name lead to overwriting:

Example:

```
http://www.stackoverflow?myparam=value1&myparam=value2
```

Will this lead to myparam holding the values "value1,value2" or only "value2" (due to overwriting and only using the last one). Is this behaviour mandated by some standard?

thanks
bernhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web servers do not consider the query at all; they just use the path to find the corresponding file below the document root. The rest is up to the handler if that targeted file is intended to be handled by a specific handler (like files ending with `.php`, `.asp`, `.shtml`, etc.). The [specification of *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) does not say anything about that neither.

So it’s not specified how to handle repeated names and thus probably up to the language/program that interprets such a query.

Comment: thanks, thats interesting to hear that this is not specified somewhere.

Comment: @bernhard: You could conclude that as *multipart/form-data* specifies that names are unique in a form (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388#section-3), this does also apply to *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. But when you think of checkbox controls, they must have the same name to be considered as a group. So in the end it depends on the interpreter that interprets the form data how to handle such cases.

Answer (score 2):

While there is nothing in [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) or [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) that expressly forbids this for requests using **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** it is forbidden for forms using **multipart/form-data** so I try to steer clear of doing it for all POST and GET requests. I think the RFCs should really address this head on.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-3 (HT @Gumbo)

> Definition of multipart/form-data
>
> The media-type multipart/form-data follows the rules of all
> multipart    MIME data streams as outlined in [RFC 2046].  In forms,
> there are a    series of fields to be supplied by the user who fills
> out the form.    Each field has a name. Within a given form, the names
> are unique.

While many languages / frameworks support pragmas that encourage encourage doing this (e.g. Ruby on Rails, PHP) it's not supported well in all client libraries and can cause serialisation problems.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the HTTP URI query part is not defined by the HTTP spec at all.

The structure that you see is an artifact of the way HTML handles forms, nothing else.